# ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: git, ssh, windows-xp, key

I am trying to add ssh keys for usage on github but on my xp on command prompt ssh-keygen does not work. It gives me the following error

```
ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

Is there an alternative for generating keys on xp?

Comment: A downvote question that earned me the notable question badge. Weird are the ways of donwvoting.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Are you running [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), or some other form of Windows git installation? msysgit is only one possible way to run git on Windows but it's probably also the simplest one. It's also the way recommended by the git website at http://git-scm.org/ .

If you *are* using msysgit, then you need to run the command in Git Bash, not in a standard Windows command line prompt. Git Bash is a prompt that is installed for you by msysgit, and is basically the most common Linux command line shell (bash) packaged for Windows to facilitate command line usage of git. msysgit should also install the ssh-keygen program in a place where it is accessible from Git Bash, but not necessarily from your usual Windows command line prompt.

Answer (score 43):

**STEP 1** Install [Git](http://git-scm.com/download/win).

**STEP 2** Add the path of your **git** to the environment variables like this **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin**.

**STEP 3** Open new terminal session and try **ssh-keygen**. It will work.

**NOTE** New Terminal Window is must!

Comment: Very helpful. Nice precise Answer! DO not forget to open the NEW CMD WINDOW!

Comment: sometimes git might be installed in **C:\Program Files\Git\bin** so verify the git existence and add the path.

Comment: In my case the "ssh-keygen.exe" was placed under user folder i-e. C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin

Comment: I've add the `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to the `System Environment Variable\Path` https://imgur.com/xVWwqew , but it still doesn't work. in the `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` there is no `ssh-keygen.exe` https://imgur.com/al12otX . Do you know What's my problem and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

If you previously installed Git, open a git-bash and try the command from there.

Answer (score 9):

Search your git directory if you already install git

Use git bash should be on your C:\Program Files\Git\bin depend on your installation location

If you already add the path just run **sh** on your **cmd** or open **sh.exe**

type **ssh-keygen**

Then just insert name and passphrase (You can just type empty string).

Answer (score 3):

Running git bash as an admin worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

for all windows os

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
ssh-keygen
```

Answer (score 1):

if you run from cmd on windows check the path System Variable value must have inside C:\Program Files\Git\bin 
or the path of you git installation 
on cmd type set to see the variables

Answer (score 1):

- Install msysgit
- Right-click on any file
- Select "**Select Git Bash here**" from menu
- Run **ssh-keygen** command from a git bash terminal

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
```

Add this to the envvars and reopen cmd. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

cd C:\Program Files\Git\bin\ssh-keygen

it works fine on my laptop

Answer (score -1):

ssh-keygen is a utility usually found on Linux distributions.  You can use Cygwin on Windows to have most functionality of the Linux command line available to you.

http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: But the ssh command works on my command prompt on Windows 7? Also wondering would cygwin in any way conflict with git?

Comment: You must have installed openssh client or something like it to be able to use it with the Windows 7 command prompt.  Cygwin won't conflict with git, you should be able to use git in Cygwin and the command prompt at any time. You might even find that Cygwin is a lot easier to deal with than the CP.

Comment: Pardon me but it is very complicated to install Cygwin, would there be another alternative?

Comment: Eclipse can generate key-pair in pure Java.
Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2