# Generate new ssh keys in Windows 10 / 11

Tags: windows-10, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen, windows-11

I am having a really hard time getting my SSH keys up and running after installing Windows 10. Normal method is create it and throw it in the user's account under `.ssh`.  But this folder does not appear to be available in Windows 10.

I need to have 3 SSH keys for different repos.

Comment: Not related but Windows 11 has OpenSSH installed by default now. So running `ssh-keygen` should just work.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wMnDpTWDLg watch here

Answer (score 200):

1. Open the windows command line (type "cmd" on the search box and hit enter).
2. It'll default to your home folder, so you don't need to `cd` to a different one.
3. Type `ssh-keygen`(if not found, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146398/ssh-keygen-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command))
4. Leave the first parameter empty(default), enter a password if you like, or leave it empty
5. Your ssh keys should be stored at chosed directory, the default is: `/c/Users/YourUserName/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

p.s.:  If you installed git with bash integration (like me) open "Git Bash" instead of "cmd" on first step

Comment: this looks great except it doesn't work. there is no command `ssh-keygen`

Comment: for some reason i had to run the `ssh-keygen` command in the git-bash shell instead of the cmd-shell.

Comment: For that you can use Git Bash sheel or git cmd , You can not use Windows cmd.

Comment: This solution was not working for me in Powershell.  But once I applied the advice of others in these comments to use the git bash shell instead, it worked great.

Comment: And what about the private keys to connect to other hosts? Should they be in this folder too?

Comment: As of Dec 2018, it worked out of the box in Win 10 for me

Comment: @Suncatcher Yes. For logging into Github, DigitalOcean, etc. you need the public key which is in "id_rsa.pub" in the same folder. Open it with a text editor like notepad and copy and paste wherever you need to add your SSH key.

Comment: Incase anybody still does not know, for it to work in CMD you need OpenSSH installed, i think it is standard now.

Comment: Last Windows version as of 12/11/2019, has ssh-keygen command, so worked perfectly.

Comment: Worked for me with Windows 10 cmd-shell. I needed to start it as administrator to generate the key.

Comment: The easiest way to copy to clipboard is running `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip`

Comment: This answer is incomplete and does not state how to generate very secure keys.

Answer (score 63):

2019-04-07 UPDATE:
I tested today with a new version of windows 10 (build 1809, "2018 October's update") and not only the open SSH client is no longer in beta, as it is already installed. So, all you need to do is create the key and set your client to use open SSH instead of putty(pagent):

1. open command prompt (cmd)
2. enter `ssh-keygen`and press enter
3. press enter to all settings. now your key is saved in c:\Users\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
4. Open your git client and set it to use open SSH

I tested on Git Extensions and Source Tree and it worked with my personal repo in GitHub.
If you are in an earlier windows version or prefer a graphical client for SSH, please read below.

2018-06-04 UDPATE:

On windows 10, starting with version 1709 (win+R and type `winver` to find the build number), Microsoft is releasing a beta of the OpenSSH client and server.
To be able to create a key, you'll need to install the OpenSSH server. To do this follow these steps:

1. open the start menu
2. Type "optional feature"
3. select "Add an optional feature"
4. Click "Add a feature"
5. Install "Open SSH Client"
6. Restart the computer

Now you can open a prompt and `ssh-keygen` and the client will be recognized by windows. I have not tested this.
If you do not have windows 10 or do not want to use the beta, follow the instructions below on how to use putty.

---

`ssh-keygen` does not come installed with windows. Here's how to create an ssh key with Putty:

1. Install [putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)
2. Open PuttyGen
3. Check the Type of key and number of bytes to use[image: PuttyGen parameters]
4. Move the mouse over the progress bar [image: generating key with mouse input]
5. Now you can define a passphrase and save the public and private keys [image: key created dialog]

For openssh keys, a few more steps are required:

1. copy the text from "Public key for pasting" textbox and save it as "id_rsa.pub"
2. To save the private key in the openssh format, go to Conversions->Export OpenSSH key ( if you did not define a passkey it will ask you to confirm that you do not want a pass key)
   [image: menu for converting key to OpenSSH format]
3. Save it as "id_rsa"

Now that the keys are saved. Start `pagent` and add the private key there ( the ppk file in Putty's format)
[image: pagent keys dialog]

Remember that `pagent` must be running for the authentication to work

Comment: ssh-keygen is included in windows 10, not sure which version, in "Manage Optional Features"

Comment: @sebbu Indeed, Now on windows 10 you can install a beta of the Open SSH Server in the "Manage Optional Features" and that will get you ssh-keygen along with a few other things. But it doesn't come installed and it's not exactly easy to find. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @KarlMorrison pagent is the gui to perform the ssh authentication. it's usually found in the start menu.

Comment: You do not need to install the Open SSH Server. The Open SSH Client feature includes ssh-keygen.

Comment: @Onots I tested with a new version of windows 10 (2018 October update) and not only open ssh client is enough, but it already comes installed :D I'll update my answer

Comment: This answer is incomplete and does not state how to generate very secure keys.

Comment: @avia What part of the answer is incomplete? What do mean by "not very secure" keys?

Comment: @franksands Thanks for the reply. What I mean by that, is that more secure keys could be generated using optional attributes. You could read ssh-keygen man page to learn more.

Comment: upvote for the udpate. could you elaborate how to do step 4 Open your git client and set it to use open SSH? What's git client? i just want to see my public key.

Comment: @K Y it depends on the client you use. I tested at the time with Git Extensions and source tree. I currently don't have that setup anymore, but I'll try to set it up and test it again

Answer (score 37):

WINDOWS: 
If you have git for windows installed go to its folder.

[image]

Look in the bin directory. There is a sh.exe file. Run that.

[image]

Then type:

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your email here"

Follow through instructions and then type:

> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip

It copies the key to your clipboard.
Now you can paste that public key to the server side.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and does not state how to generate very secure keys.

Answer (score 12):

1. Open the windows command line (type "cmd" on the search box and hit enter).
2. It'll default to your home folder, so you don't need to `cd` to a different one.
3. Type `mkdir .ssh`

Comment: This answer is incomplete and does not state how to generate very secure keys.

Answer (score 11):

**Warning:** If you are saving your keys under **C:/User/username/.ssh** ( the default place), make sure to back up your keys somewhere (eg your password manager).

After the most recent Windows 10 Update (version 1607), my .ssh folder was empty. This is where my keys have always been, but Windows decided to delete them when updating.

Thankfully I had backed up my keys... But... I bet some people will be reverting their PC's today.

Comment: So where do most apps expect you to store your keys?

Comment: probably in the folder that windows randomly deletes when upgrading windows 10?

Answer (score 11):

I'm running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763, and I see my .ssh folder easily at C:\Users\jrosario\.ssh without having to edit permissions or anything (though in File Explorer, I did select "Show hidden files, folders and drives"):
[image]

The keys are stored in a text file named known_hosts, which looks roughly like this:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

I found a notable exception that in Windows 10, using the described route only wrote the files to the folder if the file names where *not specified* in the ssh-keygen generator.

giving a custom key name caused the files containing the RSA public and private keys not to be written to the folder.

- Open the windows command line
- Type `ssh-keygen`
- Leave file name blank, just press return,
- Set your passphrase
- Generate your key files. They will now exist. and be stored in `c:/Users/YourUserName/.ssh/`

(*using Admin Command Line and Windows 10 Pro*)

Comment: @Braineeee negative. This will ***NOT*** overwrite your keys, if keys currently exist in the destination then on the Command-line Window it will ask you if you wish to overwrite these keys. Other keys in the same folder **are not effected**. I know as after reading your comment I did a test run and found this to be so.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why?

Comment: @Damainman unfortunately I've not yet had a chance to explore this more, so no `:-/`

Comment: Thanks @Martin you saved my day.

I am able to create the files with different named. We have to provide the path separator in unix way!

The following worked for me.
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "My Github Key"

Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\bilix/.ssh/id_ed25519): **c:\users\bilix\.ssh\id_ed25519_github**

Answer (score 6):

Create private/public key:

1. Open up terminal (`git bash`, `PowerShell`, `cmd.exe` etc.)
2. Type in `ssh-keygen`
3. Press enter for default file save (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`)
4. Press enter for default passphrase (no passphrase)
5. Press enter again
6. Look at the output and make sure that the `RSA` is `3072` or above

You have now created a private/public key pair.

For GIT the key must have a strength of `2048`, must be located in the users `.ssh` directory and be called `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. **When pasting the keys anywhere make sure to use a program that does not add new lines like VIM.**

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can try (for Windows 10 Pro)
Run Powershell as administrator and type `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Also, you can try to run `ssh-keygen` from Git Bash terminal

Answer (score 3):

All these answers generate default keys that are not secure enough. This answer suggests ONE (1 of MANY) ways to generate SAFE keys. I would rather use my answer over other answers on this page ... by far...

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows 10 with the OpenSSH client you may be able to generate the key, but you will have trouble copying it to the target Linux box as the ssh-copy-id command is not part of the client toolset.

Having has this problem I wrote a small PowerShell function to address this, that you add to your profile.

```
function ssh-copy-id([string]$userAtMachine, [string]$port = 22) {   
    # Get the generated public key
    $key = "$ENV:USERPROFILE" + "/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
    # Verify that it exists
    if (!(Test-Path "$key")) {
        # Alert user
        Write-Error "ERROR: '$key' does not exist!"            
    }
    else {  
        # Copy the public key across
        & cat "$key" | ssh $userAtMachine -p $port "umask 077; test -d .ssh || mkdir .ssh ; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys || exit 1"      
    }
}
```

You can get the [gist](https://gist.github.com/conradakunga/7a20df44075066f8a9053a5dc91af44f#file-ssh-copy-id-ps1) here

I have a brief write up about it [here](https://www.conradakunga.com/blog/copy-ssh-key-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work by running opening command line with "Run a Administrator" even though I was already admin and could create directory manually

Comment: -t rsa -b 4096 -t rsa -b 4096