# I've used Git with Github, but now I need to use it with something else. How can I add another SSH key?

Tags: git

Sorry if this is not the right stackexchange.

I have used Git with Github and that works well.

I now want to use Git with my own website which is on a live site.  My host provided me with a private SSH key specifically for my domain.  The key was generated via a Git add-on for cPanel.

How can I add this second key, and then how does Git know which key to use?

I'm totally noob to this but I've been Googling for hours about this.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a key to github, or how to connect to a git repo which resides on a web server?

Comment: I'll edit the question

Comment: Does that make it clearer?  I want to connect to a git repro on a web server, but I also at times will want to connect to Github.  I already set up Github so that part works.  I need to know how to add a different set up, and switch between the two.

Comment: *“My host provided me with an SSH key”* – Did your host give you a *private* key which you should use to communicate with your server? That’s a big red flag, do not accept that. Private keys should *never* be shared.

Comment: The host gave me a private key yes.  It's individual for my domain name.  Have updated the question in case others think the same.  Cheers for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily.  If you add the new key to your .ssh/ folder, and ssh-add your new key.  The following link explains this process for two different github repositories, but you should be able to adapt for your case.

https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: Thanks.  These are the types of articles I've read.  I guess my question is.... where is ~/.ssh/  any folder I find with /ssh/ doesn't seem to have a key stored in it, but I must have stored one somewhere to use Github right?

Comment: What platform are you on?  OS X? Linux? Windows?

Comment: Windows does some funky stuff, and your git client / shell will determine the location of .ssh.  See these two threads: http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813080/windows-10-ssh-keys .  Either you or your client must have made one though if you are pushing to your github repositories without ever needing a password.  Check Github.com>Settings>SSH and GPG keys to confirm that you are authenticating through an RSA key pair.

Comment: Thanks I'll try those links, that seems much closer to what I need.  Finally someone understands my question :)  That's the trouble when you don't know what you're doing, you don't know the right question to ask!