# How to configure git with SSH keys on Windows 10?

Tags: git

I downloaded and installed git from: https://git-scm.com/downloads. I can use git on Windows Command Prompt now.

I downloaded puttygen and used it to generate a pair of RSA keys, stored at `D:\rsa_keys`

I added the public key to my company's git website.

Now, how can I tell git to use the rsa key I just created?

Comment: Create a .ssh dir in git's home directory and it'll use them automatically. So i.e. `$HOME\.ssh\id_rsa`

Comment: what is $HOME in Windows?

Comment: Start your git bash and it will be the path your shell starts in at the beginning.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I tell Git for Windows where to find my private RSA key?](https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key)

Comment: Type `pwd` and you'll see your path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 SSH keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813080/windows-10-ssh-keys)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wMnDpTWDLg

Answer (score 4):

I think you may need to run git bash and set keys there:

1. Start git bash (the simplest way: `All Programs -> Git -> Git Bash`
2. In the git bash terminal type `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. This will generate public and private key pair
3. Go to the location of the keys (I'd recommend using git bash for it) and open the public key (with cat, for example), copy it
4. Paste the public key on your github account using `Account->SSH Keys->Add key`

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the OP's question. They already created the keys and they already copied the public key their company's website. The question as I read it is "Given a pre-existing set of keys in a unique location, how to point local Git to find and use those keys?"

Comment: The answer to the question is mostly in the beginning:
I think you may need to run git bash and set keys there:
1. Start git bash (the simplest way: All Programs -> Git -> Git Bash
That's what worked for me. The other items are just to "complete" the answer with more details. If my answer is not the answer, what is your answer then?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 I wasn't able to just use the SSH public/private key pair as generated on GitHub.

I had to first convert the private key to a .ppk format. To do this, open *PuTTY Key Generator*, go to `Conversions -> Import Key`. Choose your private key, and then click on `Save private key`. You'll have your private key in a `.ppk` file.

After that, you need *Pageant* (*PuTTY Authenticator Agen*t) to be aware of that key. Open Pageant and add the private key with the `.ppk` file you just created.

This allowed me to authenticate with GitHub correctly.