# where to put ssh keys of git for use in windows 10

Tags: git, ssh, windows-10

I have installed git on ubuntu 19.10 and it works fine with my ssh keys.
I installed gitbash on windows 10 and I want to use same keys on windows 10.
I checked this thread https://serverfault.com/a/198691 and also [How to configure git with SSH keys on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023197/how-to-configure-git-with-ssh-keys-on-windows-10)
I do not see any folder name .ssh in my Git installation directory on Windows 10.
I only see folllowing folders and files

```
bin
cmd
dev
etc
git-bash.exe
git-cmd.exe
LICENSE.txt
mingw64
ReleaseNotes.html
tmp
unins000.dat
unins000.exe
unins000.msg
usr
```

I don't see any where any folder where I can put ssh keys inside to use.
I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your keys in `%USERPROFILE%`, which is set as `$HOME` by default in git bash.

You can also set, in your git bash session:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
```

That way, with any git command using ssh (like a git clone), you will see exactly what Git is trying to access to)