# I want to get a SSH key for gitlab for uploading my project. But for creating a key that command line doesn't work

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keygen

Here is the screen capture for the problem:

[image: error]

In command-line(CMD):

```
> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "..."
'ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external program.
```

How to generate ssh key? How can I use `ssh-keygen`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146398/ssh-keygen-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Git for Windows, with a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359814/6309) and a portable Git (like [`PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.21.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit.7z.exe)), uncompressed anywhere you want.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

In that CMD (run as a regular user, not admin), you should have `ssh-keygen` available.

Example for me:

```
vonc@VONC D:\
> where ssh-keygen
D:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin\ssh-keygen.exe
```

But, due to [a recent openssh change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309), use:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f afile
```

You will have a key compatible with classic PEM listeners.